# Flutter conflicting dependency when running integration tests

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, mobile

I have imported two libraries which have classes of the same name. I have tried to reslove the conflict by aliasing the imports across the project where used. I have also tried creating a small blank project using only these two imports and I am still unable to run an integration test.

The two dependencies are

https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_cluster_manager/example
https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter/versions

I made the dummy project with the example code in cluster manager.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:example/place.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_cluster_manager/google_maps_cluster_manager.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cluster Manager Demo',
      home: MapSample(),
    );
  }
}

// Clustering maps

class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  late ClusterManager _manager;

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  Set<Marker> markers = Set();

  final CameraPosition _parisCameraPosition =
      CameraPosition(target: LatLng(48.856613, 2.352222), zoom: 12.0);

  List<Place> items = [
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      Place(
          name: 'Place $i',
          latLng: LatLng(48.848200 + i * 0.001, 2.319124 + i * 0.001)),
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      Place(
          name: 'Restaurant $i',
          isClosed: i % 2 == 0,
          latLng: LatLng(48.858265 - i * 0.001, 2.350107 + i * 0.001)),
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      Place(
          name: 'Bar $i',
          latLng: LatLng(48.858265 + i * 0.01, 2.350107 - i * 0.01)),
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      Place(
          name: 'Hotel $i',
          latLng: LatLng(48.858265 - i * 0.1, 2.350107 - i * 0.01)),
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      Place(
          name: 'Test $i',
          latLng: LatLng(66.160507 + i * 0.1, -153.369141 + i * 0.1)),
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      Place(
          name: 'Test2 $i',
          latLng: LatLng(-36.848461 + i * 1, 169.763336 + i * 1)),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _manager = _initClusterManager();
    super.initState();
  }

  ClusterManager _initClusterManager() {
    return ClusterManager<Place>(items, _updateMarkers,
        markerBuilder: _markerBuilder);
  }

  void _updateMarkers(Set<Marker> markers) {
    print('Updated ${markers.length} markers');
    setState(() {
      this.markers = markers;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: _parisCameraPosition,
          markers: markers,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _controller.complete(controller);
            _manager.setMapId(controller.mapId);
          },
          onCameraMove: _manager.onCameraMove,
          onCameraIdle: _manager.updateMap),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _manager.setItems(<Place>[
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
              Place(
                  name: 'New Place ${DateTime.now()} $i',
                  latLng: LatLng(48.858265 + i * 0.01, 2.350107))
          ]);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.update),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Marker> Function(Cluster<Place>) get _markerBuilder =>
      (cluster) async {
        return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(cluster.getId()),
          position: cluster.location,
          onTap: () {
            print('---- $cluster');
            cluster.items.forEach((p) => print(p));
          },
          icon: await _getMarkerBitmap(cluster.isMultiple ? 125 : 75,
              text: cluster.isMultiple ? cluster.count.toString() : null),
        );
      };

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> _getMarkerBitmap(int size, {String? text}) async {
    if (kIsWeb) size = (size / 2).floor();

    final PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    final Paint paint1 = Paint()..color = Colors.orange;
    final Paint paint2 = Paint()..color = Colors.white;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size / 2, size / 2), size / 2.0, paint1);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size / 2, size / 2), size / 2.2, paint2);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size / 2, size / 2), size / 2.8, paint1);

    if (text != null) {
      TextPainter painter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
      painter.text = TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: size / 3,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
      );
      painter.layout();
      painter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(size / 2 - painter.width / 2, size / 2 - painter.height / 2),
      );
    }

    final img = await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size, size);
    final data = await img.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png) as ByteData;

    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
}
```

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_maps_cluster_manager-3.1.0/lib/src/cluster_manager.dart:8:1: Error: 'Cluster' is imported from both 'package:google_maps_cluster_manager/src/cluster.dart' and 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/types/cluster.dart'.
import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart';
```

Cleaning and rebuilding cache does not seem to work either. Is there any way to alias these dependencies to stop them conflicting?

I was expecting to be able to use both libraries without conflict. I have tried to alias in the files where the dependencies are used as as well as hiding 'Cluster' which is causing the conflict.

Comment: What happens when you use aliasing and hiding? Is there any other issue that comes with it?

Comment: With hiding it shows `The library 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' doesn't export a member with the hidden name 'Cluster'.` even though there is conflict. With aliasing it's the same as the original error when it will not build because of conflict between the two libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your error,

```
Error: 'Cluster' is imported from both 'package:google_maps_cluster_manager/src/cluster.dart' and 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/types/cluster.dart'.
import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart'
```

This indicates that both packages have the name `Cluster` in it and Dart doesn't know which one you want to use for your project.

This is called [ambiguous imports](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=ambiguous_import#ambiguous_import) as per the Dart documentation.

> *The analyzer produces this diagnostic when a name is referenced that is declared in two or more imported libraries.*

The most common fixes are the following:

1. If any of the libraries aren't needed, then remove the import directives for them. Just remove the interface library if you think they already exist on the other library and just use what's needed.
2. If the name is still defined by more than one library, then add a `hide` clause to the import directives for all except one library that you want to use the name from. In this case, you can hide the `Cluster` from the interface package so that you can use it from the cluster manager package. You can do the other way around if you prefer:

   ```
   import 'package:google_maps_cluster_manager/google_maps_cluster_manager.dart';
   import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart' hide Cluster;
   ```
3. If you must be able to reference more than one of these types, then add a prefix (`as`) to each of the import directives, and qualify the references with the appropriate prefix:

   ```
   import 'package:google_maps_cluster_manager/google_maps_cluster_manager.dart' as MapsClusterer;
   import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart' as MapsInterface;

   // Then you can use the `Cluster` from both packages by using dot notation.
   MapsClusterer.Cluster
   MapsInterface.Cluster
   ```

This fixed the error when I tried it on a sample app I had.

> NOTE: I can see that you have mentioned that you already tried the aforementioned fixes but I don't see it in your sample code. And it seems a bit unclear as to why it did not work for you after trying. So I'll just be leaving this here in case you missed something / for posterity.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried to use the prefix "as" but still got the error when building. I am not able to post the entire code but I used the prefix as follows

`import 'package:google_maps_cluster_manager/google_maps_cluster_manager.dart'as GoogleCluster;
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart'as GoogleMaps;
`


And then used the alias for example
`GoogleMaps.CameraPosition(target: GoogleMaps.LatLng(48.856613, 2.352222), zoom: 12.0);
`

I get a similar problem with hiding. I notice we are using different imports, I am unable to use that import

Comment: If I use 
`import 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.dart' hide Cluster;`

GoogleMap and GoogleMapController are no longer imported and these are required.

with 
`import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';`
I am unable to hide Cluster and ClusterManager because
`The library 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart' doesn't export a member with the hidden name 'Cluster'.`
Although when building this is a conflict.

Comment: From what I tested so far, the GoogleMap and GoogleMapController are available in the ‘google_maps_flutter’ . Why is it not being detected?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm really not sure. It is the same for both the actual project and the test project. Perhaps we are using different versions?
`google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6`

`google_maps_cluster_manager: ^3.0.0+1`